# Internet explorer <h1> <a> not showing

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Hi i'm new in web developement, i have three browsers : `google Chrome` , `Mozilla FireFox` and `Internet Explorer 11`, i'm creating login page, everything is ok in `Google Chrome` and `Mozilla FireFox`, where the result is like :[image]

but in internet explorer The result is like :
[image]

The Html code is like :

```html
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Connexion</h1>
        <!-- Some PHP code -->
        <form method='post' action=''>  
            <input type="email" name="email"  placeholder="Votre email" value="<?php echo isset($email) ? $email :'';?>"> 
            <br><br> 
            <input type="password"  placeholder="Votre mot de passe" name="password"> 
            <br><br> 
            <div class="select-style">
                <select name="type" placeholder="Type de compte">
                    <?php echo isset($type) ?'<option value='.$type.'>'.$type.'</option>': '';?>
                    <?php echo $type!='Médecin' ? '<option value="Médecin">Médecin</option>' :'';?>
                    <?php echo $type!='Patient' ? '<option value="Patient">Patient</option>' :'';?>  
                </select>
            </div>
            <br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Se connecter" name="submit">

        </form> 
        <div class="lien">
            <a href="index.php?page=registerMed">Créer un compte Médecin</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="index.php?page=register">Créer un compte Patient</a>
        </div>
    </center> 
</body>
```

the css is like :

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,400,700);

input {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 3px solid rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.6);
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 400px;
    font-family: Raleway, Open Sans, Droid Sans;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input:focus {
    border-color: #2875A8;
}

input[type=submit] {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background: rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.6);
    border: 0 none;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background: #3DB7FF;
}

input[type=submit]:focus {
    background: #2875A8;
}

.error {
    padding: 10px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #d30000;
}

body {
    background-color: #3498db;
    font-family: Raleway, Open Sans, Droid Sans;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: rgba(180, 180, 180, 0);
    padding: 0px 5px  0px 5px;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    background-color: #3DB7FF;
    padding: 0px 5px  0px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.select-style {
    border: 3px solid  rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.6);
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.6);
    background: #fff url("http://www.scottgood.com/jsg/blog.nsf/images/arrowdown.gif") no-repeat 90% 50%;
}

.select-style select {
    padding: 5px 8px;
    border: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: Raleway, Open Sans, Droid Sans;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

.content {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 60%;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .3s ease;
    transition: box-shadow .3s ease;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    background-color: rgba(210, 210, 255, 0.6);
    margin: 50px auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.content form {
    padding: 30px;
}

.content form input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=password] {
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70%;
}

.content form input[type=submit] {
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.6);
}

.fullBg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.lien {
    background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.6);
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

**THE FIX**
 the link :http://rechmed.byethost9.com/index.php?page=login

i fixed it by adding this css code

```
.center{
margin-left:15%;
width:70%;
float:left; 
text-align:center;
}
```

and replacing `<center>` with this div

```
   <div class:"center">what i want it to be center</div>
```

the dropdown arrow was hided now with

```
 select::-ms-expand {display:none}
```

thank you very much for your comments ;) you helped me alot

Comment: so what shall i use ?

Comment: I'm not sure but the `<center>` element is also deprecated. You should run your code through a validator first.

Comment: IE supports the form element. I don't know about the center element though. Try taking that out and see if it renders correctly.

Comment: @TylerH Since when does IE not support the `<form>` tag? But ya the `<center>` tag should be removed

Comment: Have u cleard your cache on IE? It can be done quick with ctrl + shift + delete

Comment: @zgood Sorry, I was thinking of associating input and submit buttons with a form.

Comment: @CharafEddineMechalikh Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9yjrj5hp/1/) demoing the code you provided above. It looks the same in Chrome and IE. So there must be something else going on. Also the dropdown arrow of the `<select>` is part of the browser and you can't remove or style it in IE as far as I know (the `appearance:none;` you are using doesn't work in IE, see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=appearance)). You'd have to create your own dropdown using `<div>`'s or `<ul>`'s or use a plugin instead of using a `<select>` element

Comment: Can u share a public link with non-working version?

Comment: i removed the <center> and the <h1> was displayed very well but the link at the bottom-right still not shown

Comment: i tried this 
<h1 align="center">Connexion</h1> .. the same problem

Comment: @CharafEddineMechalikh what about `<h1 style="text-align:center">....`

Comment: uff, seems that I will have to install IE for testing purposes

Comment: This maybe a silly question, but where's the rest of your markup? `<!doctype html><html><head>...</head><body>your markup</body></html>`?

Comment: you're right by asking that question ... i posted here just the body because i think the head does'nt help here

Comment: are you doing it on a localhost? if not can you trow us a link?

Comment: i will try to apload it

Comment: Does anyone else half on a 'C' to the left of the bottom left red circle in the second picture? Are the links being covered by another element?

Comment: yes i clear the cache in every try

Comment: http://rechmed.byethost9.com/index.php?page=login